# Whats wrong with this code? (java) ( error: cannot find symbol method getValue() )

Tags: java, jsoup

The places with ** around them throw *cannot find symbol method getValue()* error.

The code by the way is part of a program to check validity of mine-craft account names; if they're available or not.

```
 public String connectToMigrate() {
  try {
  Connection.Response response = 
    Jsoup.connect("https://account.mojang.com/migrate").execute();
  Document doc = response.parse();
  Element authToken = doc.select("input[name^=authenticityToken]").get(0);
  Map cookies = response.cookies();
  Connection connection = 
    Jsoup.connect("https://account.mojang.com/migrate/check")
    .data("authenticityToken", authToken.val())
    .data("mcusername", this.username)
    .data("password", this.password)
    .method(Connection.Method.POST)
    .followRedirects(true);
  connection.timeout(10000);
  for (Object cookie : cookies.entrySet()) {
      connection.cookie((String) **cookie.getValue**(), (String)  **cookie.getKey**());
  }
  Connection.Response postResponse = connection.execute();
  if (postResponse.body().toLowerCase().contains("invalid username"))
    return "error";
  if (postResponse.body().toLowerCase().contains("already been migrated"))
    return "error";
  if (postResponse.body().toLowerCase().contains("locked out"))
    return "error";
  if (postResponse.body().toLowerCase().contains("bought minecraft"))
    return "error";
  if (postResponse.body().toLowerCase().contains("too many failed attempts")) {
    getNewProxy();
    return "try again";
  }
  if (postResponse.body().toLowerCase().contains("error")) {
    return "try again";
  }

  Map cookies2 = postResponse.cookies();
  Connection connection2 = 
    Jsoup.connect("https://account.mojang.com/migrate/chooseEmail");
  for (Object cookie : cookies2.entrySet()) {
      connection2.cookie((String) **cookie.getValue()**, (String) **cookie.getKey()**);
  }
  connection2.timeout(10000);
  Connection.Response postResponse2 = connection2.execute();
  String s = postResponse2.body().toLowerCase();
  s = s.split("i want to use <strong>")[1];
  s = s.split("</strong>")[0];
  String email = s;
  return email; } catch (Exception e) {
}return "try again";
}
```

Comment: `cookie` is an object of what type?

Answer (score 2):

`cookie` is an Object which doesn't contain `getValue()` method. You need to cast it to proper type before calling `getValue()`.

Answer (score 1):

i think you just misunderstood how to use maps in java. 
it should be quite easy, try this:

```
Map<String,String> cookies = response.cookies();
[...]
for ( Map.Entry<String,String> e : cookies.entrySet()){
    connection.cookie( e.getKey(), e.getValue() );
}
```

however, you can copy all the cookies at once by doing this:

```
connection.cookies( response.cookies() );
```

Answer (score 0):

`getCookies` on the JSoup `Connection.Response` object returns a `Map<String, String>`.

So in your first `for` loop:

```
for (Object cookie : cookies.entrySet())
```

each `cookie` is a `Set`, and `Set` doesn't support these methods (see the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet%28%29)).

Instead, in these loops you should iterate over the `Map` keys, which will be the cookie names:

```
for (Object cookie : cookies.keySet())
```

Now each `cookie` **is** the key, and you can query the original map for the value with `cookies.get(cookie)`.

But Jsoup's `Connection` already allows you to copy the cookies directly (see the [docs](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html#cookies%28java.util.Map%29)), no loop necessary:

```
connection.cookies(response.cookies());
```